# Rewrite Rule from .htaccess into Apache VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /API/index.php [L]
```

Is it possible to convert the above rules into usable `VirtualHost` block?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@web-api
    DocumentRoot "/Users/shot/git/web-api"
    ServerName web-api
    ServerAlias web-api
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/web-api-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/web-api-access_log" common
    
    RewriteEngine on

    <Directory "/Users/shot/git/web-api">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /API/index.php [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But in apache error log, I get the following output
`[core:error] [pid 2520] [client 127.0.0.1:52625] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: I've answered before your subsequent edit... you had stated "inside the VirtualHost block" - which is how I've answered. However, I see you are putting the directives inside a `<Directory>` section - this is very different. Is this a requirement? Note that `.htaccess` will override this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put those directives directly inside the `VirtualHost` (ie. not inside a `<Directory>` container) then you could rewrite them like so:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/. /API/index.php [L]
```

Required changes:

- When the vhost directives are processed, the request has not yet been mapped to the filesystem, hence the need to use a look-ahead (`LA-U:REQUEST_FILENANE`) to get the resulting filename.
- In a virtualhost context, the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is root-relative, starting with a slash. So, instead of `.` in `.htacces`, you need `/.` (or `^/.`) in the vhost config.
- The `RewriteBase` directive does not apply in virtualhost context, so needs to be removed. (Although you weren't making use of this anyway in your existing `.htaccess` file.)

Additional:

- In the directive that set the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` environment variable, the *pattern* `.*` is less efficient. Better to use `^` (or similar - something that does not have to traverse the entire URL-path)
- Your initial `<IfModule>` wrapper is meaningless.

Comment: I appreciate your response. I tried your example and 404 is returned with postman at GET `http://web-api/admin/order`. This is behind Slim/Symfony framework; the URL is mapped to one of the PHP files. Am I missing something?

Comment: Also, if I used `/.` instead of `^/.`, I get the same `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects` error.

Comment: To clarify, the directives I posted above you put directly inside the `<VirtualHost>` container, not inside the `<Directory>` section? Presumably `.htaccess` has been removed? What happens when you request `/API/index.php` directly? You can put a specific check in for `/API/index.php` (which would possibly be marginally more efficient) - but it should "work" without.

Comment: I figured it out. Running php server was the answer. Your solution helped me to move in right direction. In end, I still need the `.htaccess` file. I'm going to mark your answer as correct because it's how conversion should be done.